# Is it possible to make a method inside an interface that takes list of method from that interface as parameter?

Tags: c#, interface, repository-pattern

**Edit:**

I finally decided to:

1. Add SaveChanges() method to my repository, and make saving changes optional.
2. Use TransactionScope and SaveChanges in my controller methods

The above should work and is simple to implement - this may not be the best approach, and is not direct answer to the question but it will have to do.

**Original question:**

I use the following repository pattern interface in my project:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Create(T entityToAdd);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Create(List<T> entityListToAdd);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> CreateOrUpdate(T entity);

    KeyValuePair<T, Exception> Get(int entityID);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Update(T entityToUpdate);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Update(List<T> entityListToUpdate);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Delete(int entityID);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> Delete(List<int> entityIDs);

    KeyValuePair<List<T>, Exception> GetFiltered(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    KeyValuePair<List<T>, Exception> GetFiltered<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<T,TOrderBy>> order);

    KeyValuePair<T, Exception> GetFilteredSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    KeyValuePair<bool, Exception> UpdateCustomProperty<ValueType>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<T,ValueType>> property, ValueType value);
}
```

Problem is that I designed my method to call context.SaveChanges() at the end of successful operation, and now I need to do something more complex (create objects in two different tables in the same method), and this can cause trash data if - for example - first entity is created but second is not.

I would like to add a method to my repository, that takes list of methods (from the repository) as parameter - thus, I cold execute them one by one and call SaveChanges() only if all calls succeed.

How can I do something like this? I tried messing with Funct<> but since it needs fixed amount of function variables to work, it doesn't seem very suitable for the job.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: you can parse through and array of `Action`

Comment: Unrelated but you may want to read about [primitive obsession](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession)

Comment: Take a look at this post of Rob Conery on why the repository pattern over EF is a bad idea and alternative approaches: http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: Why are all your methods returning a `KeyValuePair<X, Exception>`? This looks like a bad design to me... If you need to pass an exception to the caller, just throw it, don't return it in a KeyValuePair...

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I finally managed to "resolve" the problem with much simpler approach, I will just add SaveChanges() method to my repository and use TransctionScope inside my controllers, this seem to work the way I want, and is very simple to implement.

@ThomasLevesque:
I use this construct because I don't want to drive m,y logic by exceptions... however I must say I'm beginning to regret this approach more and more :/

Answer (score 0):

I would think about distributing responsibility between different types.

Concept may look like this:

```
public interface IDBSAve {} //generic interface 

public class Table1Saver : IDBSave {} //class that saves ONLY in Table1 
public class Table2Saver : IDBSave {} //class that saves ONLY in Table2

//business process that requires save in these 2 tables
var twoTablesBusinessProcess = new List<IDBSave> {new Table1Saver(), new Table2saver()}; 

//execute save in all calling chanin of this business process and if ALL 
//succeed, confirm commit.
if(twoTablesBusinessProcess.All(save=>save.SaveTable())) 
    context.SaveChanges();
```

I assume here that every type that derives from  `IDBSAve` interface implements `bool SaveTable(..)` method, that returns `true` if save suceed and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I actually did something similar but simpler please see my edit ;]